# Finding optimal values of parameters using observations

Tags: regression, optimization, experiment-design

I have a problem that at first seemed super easy to solve but right now I am not sure how to crunch it.

I have data with multiple observations (about 30) of certain process. Process can be modulated by set of 8 continuous parameters and it gives the result that can be easily measured. I would like to pick the optimal values of the parameters so that it maximize the result variable using the data I have gathered.

At first I was thinking that I simply use linear regression to see how increase or decrease of the parameters affect the result, but I just realised that it will only give me the direction of how I should adjust, not the optimal values. Values of parameters may not have linear relation with outcome after all.

And now I am stuck because I don't know any method that would allow me to find this optimal values (or at least approximation of them). There are some ideas that come to my mind of how I could do this, but I don't want to reinvent wheel. So can you give me a hint in what direction should I take a look at? Is there any easy method to calculate optimal values using data? (By easy I mean easy to calculate it in R or Python)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Is search costly or is there another reason you want to find the structural relationship?

Comment: Unfortunately it takes time to generate single observation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into experimental design, specifically response surface design. Or, if you already have the data, quadratic regression, since a quadratic polynomial will either have a maximum (most probably in your case since you know the process will have a maximum) or a minimum.

You should use a quadratic regression function with all variables squared and all interaction terms, at least that will be a good starting point.

There is complete books dedicated to response surface design, see [https://www.amazon.com/Response-Surfaces-Mixtures-Ridge-Analyses/dp/0470053577/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1537557175&sr=1-5&keywords=response+surface&dpID=41h-TVn0ALL&preST=_SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470053577)